# Advanced type validation with OptionsResolver component

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-components

I need allow types that implement two interfaces (`Foo` and `Bar`), not one of them.

```
interface Foo {};
interface Bar {};

class Foz implements Foo {};
class Baz implements Bar {};
class Foobar implements Foo, Bar {};

$resolver = new OptionsResolver();
$resolver->setRequired('data');
$resolver->setAllowedTypes('data', ['Foo', 'Bar']);
```

**Wrong!** allows `Foz` and `Baz` instances too.

---

I need allow types subclass of `Bar`, not `Bar` instances.

```
class Bar {};
class Foobar extends Bar {};
class FoobarBaz extends Foobar {};

$resolver = new OptionsResolver();
$resolver->setRequired('data');
$resolver->setAllowedTypes('data', ['Bar']);
```

**Wrong!** allows `Bar` instances too.

---

I can redesign my classes/interfaces but it's not a design problem. **So, is it possible achieve it with this component?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [Define a form option allowed values depending on another option value in a FormType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35204850/define-a-form-option-allowed-values-depending-on-another-option-value-in-a-formt/35215869#35215869).

You should use a **normalizer** for this:

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\InvalidConfigurationException;

$resolver->setNormalizer('data', function(Options $options, $data) {
    if (!$data instanceof Foo && !$data instanceof Bar) {
        throw new InvalidConfigurationException('"data" option must implement "Foo" and "Bar" interfaces.');
    }

    return $data;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I found a way but I'm not sure at all that it's a conventional way:

```
//...
function is_foobar($value) {
    //return true or false;
}

$resolver = new OptionsResolver();
$resolver->setRequired('data');
$resolver->setAllowedTypes('data', 'foobar');
//...
```

---

**EDIT:**

Well, after I sleep on, I think my approach is wrong, because it's already done by using `setAllowedValues` or `addAllowedValues` methods:

```
$resolver->setAllowedValues('foo', function ($value) {
    return $value instanceof Foo && $value instanceof Bar;
});
```

So it's not necessary to use `setAllowedTypes` for this purpose.

Comment: yeah if you look at symfony's `OptionsResolver` class, the `offsetGet()` function, it just checks for `if (function_exists($isFunction = 'is_'.$type))`, so yeah, surprisingly that should work - nice find! Although it's a horrible workaround let me say :)

Comment: Yes "horrible" is the word, but even worse it's the error message when invalid type: `InvalidOptionsException: The option "data" with value Baz is expected to be of type "foobar", but is of type "Baz".` :)

Answer (score 1):

The signature of `OptionsResolver::setAllowedTypes()` is just [this](http://api.symfony.com/3.1/Symfony/Component/OptionsResolver/OptionsResolver.html#method_setAllowedTypes):

```
setAllowedTypes(string $option, string|string[] $allowedTypes)
```

The argument `$allowedTypes` can accept a list of strings, and is used as a logic *OR*, so *any* of those types will be allowed - that's all you can do I'm afraid...

Note that in order to allow the complex combinations you want, you'd need either more arguments or other methods, otherwise there's no way to know whether you want "any of these types", "all of these types at the same time", "any type but these ones" or any other combination you can imagine...

I guess they may provide a method that accepts a callback function as the second argument, so you can do any crazy checks you want, but *AFAIK* that doesn't exist (yet).

Comment: thanks @MikO for your answer, I appreciate your advice (+1)